# Add a new system call at FreeBSD-11 for calculating sum of two values

Tags: kernel, system-calls, freebsd

I am a beginner in FreeBSD. I installed FreeBSD-11.0-RELEASE-amd64 on VM. I want to add the first new system call that it is for calculating the sum of two values.
But my function has errors!
mykern.c

```
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>

  struct myargs {
       unsigned int k0;
       unsigned int k1;
};

int sys_func(struct thread *td, struct myargs *uap);

int sys_func (struct thread *td, struct myargs *uap)
{
     unsigned int a,b,c;
     a = uap->k0;
     b = uap->k1;
     c = a + b;
     printf("%u + %u = %u\n",a,b,c);
     return (0);
}
```

Errro!

> usr/src/sys/kern/mykern.c:17:5: error: conflicting types for
>   'sys_func' int sys_func(struct thread *td, struct myargs *uap)
>
> /usr/src/sys/sys/sysproto.h:2180:5: note: previous declaration is here
>   int sys_func(struct thread *, struct func_args *);

I read a part from https://wiki.freebsd.org/AddingSyscalls

```
    After adding an entry to sys/kern/syscalls.master, you must regenerate the generated files in sys/kern and sys/sys:
$ make -C sys/kern/ sysent
mv -f init_sysent.c init_sysent.c.bak
mv -f syscalls.c syscalls.c.bak
mv -f systrace_args.c systrace_args.c.bak
mv -f ../sys/syscall.h ../sys/syscall.h.bak
mv -f ../sys/syscall.mk ../sys/syscall.mk.bak
mv -f ../sys/sysproto.h ../sys/sysproto.h.bak
sh makesyscalls.sh syscalls.master
```

I checked sysproto.h file and in it:

```
    struct func_args {
char uap_l_[PADL_(struct myargs *)]; struct myargs * uap; char uap_r_[PADR_(struct myargs *)];
};



sys_func(struct thread *, struct func_args*);
```

What is func_args?
Is there any solution?

Comment: You might get more support on FreeBSD IRC channels or mailing lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my code, so it has no error.
I hope it will be useful for other.

```
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>

#ifndef _SYS_SYSPROTO_H_
  struct func_args {
       unsigned int k0;
       unsigned int k1;
};
#endif


int sys_func (struct thread *td, struct func_args *uap)
{
     unsigned int a,b,c;
     a = uap->k0;
     b = uap->k1;
     c = a + b;
     printf("%u + %u = %u\n",a,b,c);
     return (0);
}
```

Comment: cmps111? I'm stuck on same thing